# Is it possible to prevent my div layers from overlapping when the browser is resized using pixel values?

Tags: html, css

I have come across an issue related overlap of div layers when the browser size is resized. then i found out that, the div properties are set with "px" values.

After checking in stackoverflow, i got to know that we should use "em" or "percentage" instead of "px" values in-order to overcome the overlap of div layers when browser size is resized.

My doubts:

why is it not possible to solve the above said problem using "px" values it self? if possible, how can i do that?.

Comment: @LGSon It works fine for the problem i have encountered. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the element's size is known, given in `px`, you can use i.e. `min-width`

```css
body > div {
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
  width: 350px;
}
div.has-min-width {
  min-width: 400px;
}
div > div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div > div:last-child {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>Hi, I'm a text that is long</div>
  <div>Hi, I'm also a longer text</div>
</div>

<div class="has-min-width">
  <div>Hi, I'm a text that is long</div>
  <div>Hi, I'm also a longer text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with in-line block elements. When the browser re-sizes they will wrap onto the next line.

https://jsfiddle.net/z9bnqzLf/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
  width:100%;
}

.box{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:red;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:5px;
}
```